# how to toggle with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have 2 buttons that can be toggled by that simple hook:

```
  const [extendDetails, setExtendDetails] = useState(false);
  const handleExtendDetails = () => setExtendDetails(!extendDetails);

  const [extendPictures, setExtendPictures] = useState(false);
  const handleExtendPictures = () => setExtendPictures(!extendPictures);
```

And these are the buttons:

```
<button onClick={handleExtendDetails}>Extend Details</button>
<button onClick={handleExtendPictures}>Extend Pictures</button>
```

Is there some sort of way to name the buttons and use `e` or some kind of a variable so I won't need to declare a hook for each button in case I've got 20 buttons and not just 2?

Comment: Could you put the button in a component? Then you can re-use it over and over again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using defining simple `Object` and `target name` combination.

```
const initialState = () => ({
  extendDetails: false,
  extendPictures: false
})

export default function App() {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(initialState())

  const handleToggle = (e) => {
    const { name } = e.target

    setToggle({ ...toggle, [name]: !toggle[name] })
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button name="extendDetails" onClick={handleToggle}>{toggle.extendDetails ? 'Open' : 'Close' } Extend Details</button>
      <button name="extendPictures" onClick={handleToggle}>{toggle.extendPictures ? 'Open' : 'Close' } Extend Pictures</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Demo link is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nq32b8)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use an array instead:

```
const [toggledButtons, setToggledButtons] = useState(() => Array.from(
  { length: 20 },
  () => false
));
```

Then you could do something like

```
const toggle = (i: number) => () => setToggledButtons(
    toggledButtons.map((current, j) => i === j ? !current : current)
);
```

```
<button onClick={toggle(0)}>Extend Details</button>
<button onClick={toggle(1)}>Extend Pictures</button>
```

Comment: Seems like toggledButtons is declared but not used. Got this error: Type '() => [boolean[], Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean[]>>]' is not an array type.

Comment: It's not shown in your original code where `extendDetails` and `extendPictures` are being used. Replace uses of those variables with `toggledButtons[0]`, `toggledButtons[1]`, etc. You could even use an object instead of an array if you think it'd make things clearer.

Comment: I understand, it looks like a good solution. The only issue now is that I use React with TypeScript (tsx file) and I get the only error message: Argument of type '(current: any, j: any) => any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<boolean[]>'.
  Type '(current: any, j: any) => any' is not assignable to type '(prevState: boolean[]) => boolean[]'.

Comment: If you're using TS, you need to indicate the type of the argument. Since `toggle` takes a number argument, type the argument as that, a number: `i: number`